# How can I add .livescript support to a em or meteor-generate?

Tags: meteor, livescript

[em](https://github.com/EventedMind/em) seems to have support for CoffeeScript but not for LiveScript, how can I add that? and secondly which scaffolding tool will be best for building Meteor applications, em or [meteor-generator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/meteor-generate) or maybe any other out there?

thanks